# BizTalk 2013 R2 - Rate based Throttling on flooding messages

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

We have a solution that takes a message, and sends it to a web API.
Every day, an automatic procedure is run by another department that passes thousands of records into the messagebox, which seems to cause errors related to the API solicit-response port (strangely these errors don't allude to a timeout, but they do only trigger when such a massive quantity of data is sent downstream).

I've contacted the service supplier to determine the capacity of their API calls, so I'll be able to tailor our flow once I have a better idea.

I've been reading up on Rate Based Throttling this morning, and have a few questions I can't find an answer to;

- If throttling is enabled, does it only process the Minimum number of samples/messages? If so, what happens to the remaining messages? I read somewhere they're queued in memory, but only of a max of 100, so where do all the others go?
- If I have 2350 messages flood through in the space of 2 seconds, and I want to control the flow, would changing my Sampling Window duration down to 1 second and setting Throttling override to initiate throttling make a difference?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Host Throttling setting, the remaining messages will be in the message box database and will show as being in a Dehydrated state.

You would have to test the throttling settings under load.  If you get it wrong it can be very bad.  I've come across one server where the settings were configured incorrectly and it is constantly throttling.

Comment: Cheers, I'm going to carry out some load testing on my dev box, luckily we use separate hosts per service, so I should be able to get the throttle config just right for that specific frequency

Comment: I'm getting a little confused between Publishing and Delivery?

If we have 2000+ messages coming in from a stored procedure, they then pass through the orchestration and get sent out to an API Call solicit-response port - would it be better to throttle on the receiving of the messages (Delivery) or the sending of the messages (Publishing)? Is there any benefit over which option to the throttle?

Comment: @mrc85 You usually are better reducing the incoming messages, otherwise you might have too many messages in the message box.  Can you make it so that your stored procedure gives you small batches, and that you poll it at an interval that means you don't hit the API limits?

Comment: Not without some massive refactoring across the whole system; we have essentially 2 sources of data which are polled (they update with over 2000 staff records on a nightly basis within the staff context), which then passes through to around 10 different BizTalk applications.
Is there any other way to control the inbound volume and essentially queue anything, or can you only queue whats technically in the message box?

Comment: @mrc85   Maybe you need to tell us exactly what error you are getting from the API.  Is it a rate limit (only allowed x number per time period), or is it concurrent connections, or is it record locking issues behind the API?   One quick and dirty way to reduce load on an API is to set the send port to Ordered delivery, which will turn it into a singleton, but may cause timeout issues in BizTalk, so you will have to test that.

Comment: There's 2 errors per message passed in: "There was a failure executing the response(receive) pipeline: ... Reason: No Disassemble stage components can recognize the data." and "Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service... There was a failure executing the response(receive) pipeline: "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "XML disassembler""

I'm assuming this is because the endpoint is flatlining with the sudden onset volume.

Comment: (Ran out of room in the above comment, these errors are paraphrased - haven't provided the specifics but theyre all the same)

Comment: Use the [edit] link and add those details to the question.   The end point is probably returning a non XML response, probably a text/html with, with an error.  Finding out what is in that error would be useful, usually I will set the response pipeline to a PassThru and have a send port subscribe to the response